# Confusion between conditional and joint probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This question might seem very trivial but I want to understand it in an intuitive way.
Let's say I have three options in a question and one of then is correct. I am randomly guessing the answer.
Now if I give the wrong answer in the first attempt I get a second chance
Then what is the probability that I will answer correctly?

I know that this answer should be `P(first attempt correct) + P(second attempt correct)`
Now what should be expression of `P(second attempt correct)`? It should be `P(correct answer and first attempt wrong)`. But I am not understanding why it should not be `P(correct answer|first attempt wrong)`?
Can someone explain it in some intuitive way? And also what is the sample space and what are the correct events?

Comment: How about sketching a [probability tree diagram](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/tree-diagrams.html)?

Comment: Hint: What would happen if you were allowed a third attempt and tried to compute $P(\text{third attempt correct})$ like that?  If it were $P(\text{correct}|\text{first two attempts wrong})$, what would be the total probability of answering correctly?

Comment: Unsure if this response will help.  If $E_1, E_2$ are two events, each with a non-zero probability of occurring, then by Bayes Theorem, you have that $$p(E_1 ~| ~E_2) = \frac{p(E_1 E_2)}{p(E_2)}.$$  Here, the LHS term is the conditional probability, and the RHS numerator is the joint probability.

Comment: It is NOT clear whether you are asking an Unconditional or a Conditional Case. The 
answer depends on what you are  looking for? Please clarify for us.

I have provided an answer under both cases which for some reason was deleted.

Comment: Harish Chandra Rajpoot, Leucippus, and amWhy: Please explain to me why my answer was deleted.  It is a big surprise and disappointment to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this answer should be `P(first attempt correct) + P(second attempt correct)` Now what should be expression of `P(second attempt correct)`? It should be `P(correct answer and first attempt wrong)`. But I am not understanding why it should not be `P(correct answer|first attempt wrong)`? Can someone explain it in some intuitive way? And also what is the sample space and what are the correct events?

You only get the second attempt if the first *fails*. (This is why the events are disjoint.)

Therefore the answer *should* be: `P(first attempt correct) + P(second attempt correct & first attempt wrong)`

Which is: `P(first attempt correct) + P(first attempt wrong) P(second attempt correct | first attempt wrong)`  by definition of conditional probability.

> And also what is the sample space and what are the correct events?

It depends on how you are guessing.  Let us say, there are $n$ possible (but only one correct), and you are selecting up to two without bias or repetition (basically: drawing without replacement).  Then the probability of obtaining the correct answer is:

$$\tfrac {1}{~n~}+\tfrac{~n-1~}{n}\cdot\tfrac{1}{~n-1~} ~=~ \tfrac {2}{~n~}$$